# Bug - Interesting Tags on homepage

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

Greetings all,

I have a question, possibly a bug, regarding the interesting tags section of the homepage.

Ok, on the home page of stackoverflow, I have added the tag BizTalk to my list of interesting tags.  As I understand it, it will highlight any questions it sees on the main page with that tag.  No problems.

However, If I click on the BizTalk tag in my interesting tag list itself, I expected it to list all questions that have been tagged BizTalk.  Right now, when I click on it, it displays nothing..  It says 0 questions tagged.  I know there is at least one question tagged BizTalk as I have asked one, plus have seen others.

What is suppose to happen on the home page when I click on a tag in the 'interesting tags' list anyways?  Does it only look for questions that appear on the home page, or does it go back in history for those items which have scrolled off the main home page?

Am I missing something?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabs under the tags view are 'sticky', which can lead to unexpected behavior. For example, if the last tab you were using was "featured" and you clicked on the <kbd>biztalk</kbd> tag, you would be greeted with a blank page because there are no featured `biztalk` questions. To correct this, select another tab (newest, votes, active, etc).

On the other hand, if you're *not* accidentally on the featured tab, then this is indeed a bug, but I can't personally reproduce it.

Comment: What you said is the case.  I changed the tab to newest and now when I click on my interesting tags, all seem find..

On a totally separate note, that seems kind of unintuitive.  This may be more due to the fact that I couldn't easily find or deduce how it works.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Yeah, it definitely needs clarification